# Dealing with empty XML in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSLT to return some values, output as XHTML. However I usually structure my XSL like this:

```
<div id="something">
  call template=Something
</div>
```

The trouble is when the XML returned is empty , it just outputs:

```
<div id="something">
Empty set.
```

And as you can imagine this screws up my page.

Is there any function I can use to detect if there is any data there or not? Or can anyone think of a better way of stopping this from happening.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be using

```
<xsl:output method="html" />
```

try

```
<xsl:output method="xml" />
```

instead.

Comment: I need to ouput as HTML, I dont want to output the RAW XML, however at somepoints nothing is returned from the XML so the XSLT messes up the page.

Comment: You said XHTML. Which is XML. The `mode="html"` is for traditional HTML output, including the possibility of unclosed tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a dirty hack, but I had the same problem and I was in a hurry, so I ended using

```
<div id="something">
    <span>call template=Something</span>
</div>
```